# How to get Location (latitude & longitude value) in variable on iOS?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, geolocation, location

I would like to use the location of my app user, more specifically the latitude and longitude value.

I need them to use in a variable, so that I can send them with an url...

I never worked before withe locations on iOS and Xcode and found nothing matching for my problem on the Internet...

So I hope someone can explain it to my with a code sample :)

Thx for u help
Laurenz from Germany

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can use CoreLocation to get the longitude and latitude.

**Include framework:**

Click your project in navigator.

Click the plus button under "link binary with libraries"

Add Corelocation to your project.

**Import the header file:**

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
```

**Declare CLLocationManager:**

```
CLLocationManager *locationManager;
```

**initialize locationManager:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; 
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

**Then, use**

```
float latitude = locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude;
float longitude = locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude;
```

Answer (score 17):

STEP 1 : Add CoreLocation framework in your project.

1. Select *TARGETS* -> *Build Phases*
2. Select *Link Binary With Libraries*
3. Click on plus *(+)* button. This will pop-up framework list.
4. Search *CoreLocation framework* and *Add* it.

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

STEP 2 : Write below code in header file of view controller where location is to be fetched :

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
```

Also, add `CLLocationManagerDelegate` in interface.

Now, create object of LocationManager

```
 CLLocationManager *locationManager;
```

STEP 3 : In, `ViewDidLoad` method write below code :

```
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization]; //Note this one
```

You can set desiredAccuracy value as `kCLLocationAccuracyBest, kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters, kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters, kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer, kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers`

Now, write below code to get latitude and longitude value

```
    float Lat = locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude;
    float Long = locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude;
    NSLog(@"Lat : %f  Long : %f",Lat,Long);
```

STEP 4 : In iOS 8, this *code fails silently* i.e you won’t get any error or warning.

You need to do two extra things to get location working:

1. **Add a key to your Info.plist**
2. **Request authorization** from the location manager asking it to start.

Any one or both of below keys needs to be added in Info.plist file.

1. **NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription**
2. **NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription**

These are of String type and value can be any message description or empty.

Now you need to request authorisation for corresponding location method. Use any one of below calls :

1. **[self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization]**
2. **[self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization]**

Answer (score 3):

Swift:

```
var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters
locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
```

More info here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CLLocationManager