# background mode firebase fetch data swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to pull data from the firebase in the background. However, after 3 minutes the background application does not work in the background. How can I withdraw data from firebase with the timer in the background? Or is there a scheduled tasks feature in the firebase?

I want to make changes to the database at a specific time. For example, I want to change a data in the firebase after 10 minutes in the background.

```
@objc func updateStateNew(){

        let ref = Database.database().reference()
        ref.child("\(chip1InfoString1!)/states/\("self.ekle2.text!")").setValue(true)

        ref.child("\(chipFieldText.text!)/states/\("001")").setValue(true)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to do that(that is acceptable by Apple reviews) is using silent push. So that you can trigger a background task any time you want(with some OS limits)
For more details see [that answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56602553/8761048)

If you don't need to run your background code on a specific time/interval, i recommend you to use [background fetch](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/scenes/preparing_your_ui_to_run_in_the_background/updating_your_app_with_background_app_refresh)

Or, the best tool but **only for iOS 13+**: [BackgroundTasks](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks)