# How to update user's current lat long to API server?

Tags: ios, location

I have a project in which I need to update the user's current location coordinates on the API server. How can I achieve this? Is continuously calling the API a good idea (I think no)?

I need to update coordinates continuously so other users can see me like in the Uber app the very first time we can see drivers near me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can implement a `timer`, and make a `POST` request by sending your lat long periodically.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var timer: Timer!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 10.0, target: self, selector: #selector(makeRequest), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    }


    @objc func makeRequest() {
        // make your post request here.
    }        

 }
```

For example the timer given above will call makeRequest method every 10 seconds.

If you don't know much about networking, make a research on the following topics:

Swift Networking Layer, Alamofire, URLSession

Comment: This will eat the background queue, Why don't you use Dispatch.main?

Comment: I'm also still a junior, how would you advise me to update my answer? @excitedmicrobe

Comment: this one update lat long after every 10 sec. is there any way so I can update lat long as I got them from didUpdateLatLong(delegate method) without any delay?

Comment: It is possible to do so, but sometimes users might change location swiftly and your api call method would be triggered maybe 10-20 times per second. You don't want to do that. Since the location update method is so sensitive, it will update itself many times for a location change. 10 was an example, but for your case, I would try to send a request every time between 2 and 5 seconds. Just try and see how it will perform. @Wdpmobile

Answer (score 0):

```
**Step 1 :- Get latitude and long. of the user first.**

Reference URL:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12736086/how-to-get-location-latitude-longitude-value-in-variable-on-ios

**Step 2:- Define following variables globally.**

    var timer:Timer? 

    var sourceLatitude = CLLocationDegrees()

    var sourceLongitude = CLLocationDegrees()

**Step 3:- Setup timer for continuous update as below.**

override func viewDidLoad() 
{
   super.viewDidLoad()

   timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 15, target: self, selector: #selector(self.updateDriverLoction), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }


**Step 4:- call appropriate method for sending and updating lat. long. to the server using any of networking API.(In my case I have used Alamofire)**

 // must be internal or public.

    @objc func updateDriverLoction() {

        if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() {

                let param1:[String:String] = [
                    "latitude" : "\(sourceLatitude)",
                    "longitude" : "\(sourceLongitude)"
                ]
                ServerClass.sharedInstance.putRequestWithUrlParameters(param1, path: BASE_CAB_URL + PROJECT_URL.UPDATE_DRIVER_LOCATION_API, successBlock: { (json) in
                    print(json)
                    let success = json["success"].stringValue
                    if success  == "true"  {
                    }
                    else {
                    }
                }, errorBlock: { (NSError) in
                    //                UIAlertController.showInfoAlertWithTitle("Alert", message:  kUnexpectedErrorAlertString, buttonTitle: "Okay")
                })
            }
        }
        else{
            UIAlertController.showInfoAlertWithTitle("Alert", message: "Please Check internet connection", buttonTitle: "Okay")
        }

}
```